# How to download the qt mobility examples package in Opensuse 11.2

Tags: qt, qt-mobility

This example: http://doc.trolltech.com/qtmobility-1.1-tp/fetchgooglemaps.html is not present in the following "qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0" directory:

```
[17:05:10 Tue May 17] ~/tarBalls/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/examples  $ls
annotatedurl             bttennis                   documentproperties     ndefeditor                    sfwecho
audiodevices             calendardemo               examples.pro           notesmanagerplugin            sfw-notes
audioinput               camera                     filemanagerplugin      publish-subscribe             slideshow
audiooutput              connectivity               flickrdemo             qmlorganizer                  sysinfo
audiorecorder            declarative-camera         hapticsplayer          qsystemalignedtimer           todo
battery-charge           declarative-connectivity   hapticsquare           querymessages                 videographicsitem
bearercloud              declarative-location       keepintouch            quickstart                    videowidget
bearermonitor            declarative-messages       landmarkbrowser        radio                         writemessage
bluetoothtransferplugin  declarative-music-browser  logfilepositionsource  samplephonebook
btchat                   declarative-sfw-dialer     mapsdemo               sensors
btfiletransfer           declarative-sfw-notes      mediabrowser           servicebrowser
btscanner                declarative-systeminfo     mobility_examples.pri  serviceinstaller_sfw_symbian
[17:08:20 Tue May 17] ~/tarBalls/qt-mobility-opensource-src-1.2.0/examples  $
```

Comment: It seems this has been removed after [version 1.0.0](http://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/qt-mobility/trees/v1.0.0).

Comment: That's a very good news :rolleyes: What I am supposed to do now? thanks for responding.

Comment: @Bart do you mean that ALL those examples WERE present in the version 1.1?

Comment: Just check the link in my first response for the Git repository. On the right hand side you have various tags for the various versions. You could even check out an older version if you wanted.

Comment: @Bart Thanks, I saw that, and I am also seeing ALL the examples in version 1.1. Now can you put this as an answer below for me to select ;)

Comment: @Bart would you also tell me the meaning of tp2 and tp1? They are attached with the qt mob versions there.

Comment: @Anisha: tp == "technical preview"

Comment: Thank you @Mat Does that mean those tagged tp shouldn't be considered for installing?

Comment: Yeah, better stick with the full version releases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FetchGoogleMaps example seems to have been removed from the Qt Mobility examples after version [1.0.0](http://www.qt.gitorious.org/qt-mobility/qt-mobility/trees/v1.0.0). You could try getting it from one of these older tags, although there is no guarantee that it will work with the recent sources and might have some bugs.

**Edit:**

As the OP has found out, there are currently two improved examples over the older FetchGoogleMaps which can be found [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/declarative-location-mapviewer.html) and [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/demos-embedded-lightmaps.html).

Comment: I am stuck in deep mud, Bart. I feel like crying and strangling the throats of the qt mobility developers :banghead: You know, this examples page is for 1.1"tp", look at the url!!! and I installed the version 1.0 right now, it is NOT compatible with qt 4.7!! WOW. And then they say that they have added some new Location API in 1.1 which are not present in 1.0?? What am I supposed to do now???

Comment: :) No need for crying. That has never helped anyone. I have not used this myself, so I'm not going to be much help in getting it to work. In general what I see online, you seem to be able to go via QtWebKit if you want a google maps connection. Perhaps you can first try the current framework and use only the example from version 1.0. If that does not work you could see if you can do something with QTWebKit yourself. If you phrase your questions clearly I find the people at http://www.qtcentre.org/ very helpful, so you might ask there as well after some experimenting. Chin up and good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your encouraging comments :hattip: AFA the Qt centre forums are concerned, they don't seem to be too active when it comes to really difficult questions. I had posted this question there too, have got zero replies! Anyway, Qt-Mobility has its own forum: http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?232-Qt-Mobility-Project and also a mailing list.

Comment: The mobility's mailing list people told me that the fetch tile example has been replaced with two better examples: 1. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/declarative-location-mapviewer.html 2. http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/demos-embedded-lightmaps.html and they are right. I ran those examples, they not only fetch the map tile but also facilitate click and zoom and pan things :)

Comment: and now if YOU put those links shown in my above comment in your answer above, it may help someone else looking for the same problem. Fly by people don't usually read comments. And also I must apologize for cursing the Qt developers ;) Thanks again for your help.

Comment: EDIT: I can't edit my previous comment now, but this is an update that the question I posted on the Qt Centre was regarding the QtMobility installation and got zero replies.

Comment: Okay, that's too bad. But good to hear you found something that works. I updated my answer with your comments. Good luck.